# How to save a string(list) from a MySQL query in Java

Tags: java, mysql, string, android-studio

I am trying to save data from a column after a query in Mysql in java but I can't do it

```
public class DataBase  {

String name;

 public void getRowdata(){


        String URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x/permisostemporales/getRowdata.php";

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < n_data; i++) {
                    try { 
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Toast.makeText(context, jsonObject.getString("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        name = jsonObject.getString("name");//This variable gives me null
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        );
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

 public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


}
```

I make the calls in the following way:
First I create the Object

```
DataBase dataBase = new DataBase (context);
  dataBase.getRowdata ();
  elements.add (dataBase.getName());//here is the problem
```

I noticed that my code compiles in the order of:

1. create the object and the getRowdata () function does nothing.
2. then it goes on to add the null value (elements.add (dataBase.getName ());) and finally recent goes to getRowdata () where it prints the toast correctly (the value I need and save in name

How would the code be so that the order makes my name value not null
and well I need to save an array of strings but use string as an example

Comment: This code seems more to be dealing with an HTTP request  returning a JSON rather than a MySQL query. Moreover it's a bit difficult to understand without an example of the response.

Comment: It is that I need to save the data of the query to later use it, but the query (OnResponde) when the program ends, then this data appears null

Comment: Have you checked the URL your code is trying to load? I have the feeling you posted a stub that you need to fill with real code.